# Помогите найти ошибку в использовании лямбды в сочетании с `std::function`

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++, stl, lambda

Использую лямбду в простом вроде бы коде:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using my_type = unsigned int;

int main()
{
    my_type def_val = -1;
auto correct_value = [&] (my_type &x, const my_type y, std::function<const my_type& (const my_type&, const my_type&)> selector)
{
  if (x != def_val)
    x = selector (x, y);
  else
    x = y;
};
    my_type x = 10;
    correct_value (x, 20, std::min<my_type>);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Но выдаёт ошибку компиляции:

```
main.cpp:18:5: error: no matching function for call to object of type '(lambda at main.cpp:10:22)'
    correct_value (x, 20, std::min<my_type>);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:22: note: candidate function not viable: no overload of 'min' matching 'std::function<const my_type &(const my_type &, const my_type &)>' (aka 'function<const unsigned int &(const unsigned int &, const unsigned int &)>') for 3rd argument
auto correct_value = [&] (my_type &x, const my_type y, std::function<const my_type& (const my_type&, const my_type&)> selector)
```

Что я сделал не так? Вроде бы 3й аргумент (функция) по прототипу соответствует. Но он всё равно ругается.

Код в онлайн-компиляторе: [тык](https://cpp.sh/?source=%2F%2F%20Example%20program%0A%23include%20%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include%20%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%0Ausing%20my_type%20%3D%20unsigned%20int%3B%0A%0Aint%20main()%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20my_type%20def_val%20%3D%20-1%3B%0Aauto%20correct_value%20%3D%20%5B%26%5D%20(my_type%20%26x%2C%20const%20my_type%20y%2C%20std%3A%3Afunction%3Cconst%20my_type%26%20(const%20my_type%26%2C%20const%20my_type%26)%3E%20selector)%0A%7B%0A%20%20if%20(x%20!%3D%20def_val)%0A%20%20%20%20x%20%3D%20selector%20(x%2C%20y)%3B%0A%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20x%20%3D%20y%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20my_type%20x%20%3D%2010%3B%0A%20%20%20%20correct_value%20(x%2C%2020%2C%20std%3A%3Amin%3Cmy_type%3E)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20std%3A%3Acout%20%3C%3C%20x%20%3C%3C%20std%3A%3Aendl%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: `std::min<my_type>` — это какая именно из [целой пачки](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) возможных `min`?

Comment: Я предполагал, что `template< class T >
const T& min( const T& a, const T& b );`

Comment: Это **вы** так предполагаете, а почему так же должен считать и компилятор?...

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что он не может выбрать из той, что я упомянул, и `template< class T >
T min( std::initializer_list<T> ilist );` ? Потому что есть только 2 варианта с 1 шаблонным параметром...

Comment: Именно так. Компилятор не терпит неоднозначности :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точно укажите компилятору, *какую именно функцию* вы имеете в виду:

```
correct_value(x, 20, 
  static_cast<const my_type & (*)(const my_type &, const my_type &)>(std::min<my_type>));
```

Код в онлайн-компиляторе: [тык](https://cpp.sh/?source=%2F%2F%20Example%20program%0D%0A%23include%20%3Ciostream%3E%0D%0A%23include%20%3Cfunctional%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Ausing%20my_type%20%3D%20unsigned%20int%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aint%20main()%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20my_type%20def_val%20%3D%20-1%3B%0D%0Aauto%20correct_value%20%3D%20%5B%26%5D%20(my_type%20%26x%2C%20const%20my_type%20y%2C%20std%3A%3Afunction%3Cconst%20my_type%26%20(const%20my_type%26%2C%20const%20my_type%26)%3E%20selector)%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(x%20!%3D%20def_val)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%20%3D%20selector%20(x%2C%20y)%3B%0D%0A%20%20else%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%20%3D%20y%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20my_type%20x%20%3D%2010%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20correct_value%20(x%2C%2020%2C%20static_cast%3Cconst%20my_type%20%26%20(*)(const%20my_type%20%26%2C%20const%20my_type%20%26)%3E(std%3A%3Amin%3Cmy_type%3E))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20std%3A%3Acout%20%3C%3C%20x%20%3C%3C%20std%3A%3Aendl%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A).

Comment: А есть ли какой-то std-шный способ сделать то же самое ? Казалось бы, довольно стандартная операция - поместить в `a` минимум из `a` и `b`, но только если `a` в определённом смысле "инициализирован", в противном случае безусловно положить туда `b`... Подобное может встретиться при реализации какого-нибудь z-буффера к примеру...

Comment: `x = (a == def_value) ? b : min(a,b);` — устроит?

Comment: В принципе да) Жаль, что не в `stl`, но ладно, главное, что кратко. Спасибо!

Comment: Да можно и с stl придумать, но смысл? Просто для того, что — а еще и вот так можно выпендриться? :)

Comment: Ну, чтобы не изобретать велосипед... казалось бы, довольно стандартная ситуация...